# RenderAction não considera minhas validações nos Models ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, web-worker

O RenderAction parou de considerar os campos marcados como `[Required]` nos meus models.

Exemplo de um dos models:

```
private uint IdNews { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Defina o título.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escreva a descrição.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^((0[1-9]|[12]\d)\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])|30\/(0[13-9]|1[0-2])|31\/(0[13578]|1[02]))\/\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "A data é inválida.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione a data de postagem.")]
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escreva o nome do Administrador que esta postando.")]
        public Admin AdminName { get; set; }

        public Image Photo { get; set; }
```

Esta é a view que esta sendo carregada com o Hrml.RenderAction:

```
@model BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Nova Notícia</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <h3>*Título</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <h4>Imagem</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" id="file"/>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <h4>*Descrição:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <br/>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Adicionar</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@*<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>*@

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

View onde são carregadas as RenderActions:

```
@using BraveryBranded.ASP.Models
@model IEnumerable<BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Notícias";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@{
    Html.RenderAction("New", "News");
}
<hr/>
@{
    Html.RenderAction("List", "News");
}
```

Comment: Luiz, no final da tua view `New` tem uma seção para scripts. Copie ela inteira para a `Index`. Depois vamos ver a questão do editor de texto.

Comment: @AndreCalil fiz isto e não mudou, sómente esta funcionando os campos de validação, porém o editor de texto que ainda não mudou nada.

Comment: O editor funciona normalmente na página isolada?

Comment: @AndreCalil Sim

Comment: @AndreCalil Uma coisa que notei é o tamanho dele, quando abre na página isolada, ele tem espaço de sobra para usar o tamanho configurado (que ainda é o padrão). Porém não sei diminuir ele, sou iniciante em .net... Será que tem a ver?

Comment: Acho que não cara, o que parece é que falta algum script para ele. Quando você adicionou o TinyMCE, seguiu algum tutorial? Link aqui para eu ver, por favor.

Comment: @AndreCalil Foi aqui: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget

Comment: @AndreCalil esta dando este erro no jquery: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tinymce' News:135
(anonymous function) News:135
fire jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
self.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.10.2.js:433
completed

Comment: Exato, está faltando algum script. Li o tutorial por cima mas não encontrei nada. Você adicionou referência a algum script qdo configurou o Tiny?

Comment: @AndreCalil Não modifiquei nada pois já saiu funcionando de cara, e ainda funciona na página quando esta sozinha. Isto que esta estranho!

Comment: @LuizNegrini Quando você salva o model com todos os campos em branco, o que acontece?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez nada, os campos de required eram somente javascripts, porém a única coisa que continua não aparecendo é o editor de texto que quero usar, se eu carrego a list na mesma página da new, não funciona, eu eu carrego sozinha, funciona de cara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido utilizando javascript. Ele estava mal posicionado na página.

Porém um dos problemas ainda persistem!

O Editor de texto TinyMCE, quando usado em uma página carregada pelo `Render Action` não funciona, se eu carregá-lo pela página da `New` e carregar o `List` com `render action`  logo abaixo, ele não abre o editor de texto. Se eu carregá-lo em uma página sozinho, funciona de cara. Se eu carregá-lo na sua própria página usando um outro `Render Action` também deixa de funcionar.